# Changing the background color of a UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uialertview

I want to change the background color of my UIAlertView, but this doesn't appear to have a color attribute.

Comment: Please mark an answer if your question was answered.

Answer (score 34):

Background of AlertView is an image
And  you can change this image

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Atention"
   message: @"YOUR MESSAGE HERE", nil)
   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

   [theAlert show];

   UILabel *theTitle = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
   [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

   UILabel *theBody = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
   [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

   UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];    
   theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16 topCapHeight:16];
   CGSize theSize = [theAlert frame].size;

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);    
   [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];    
   theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   [[theAlert layer] setContents:[theImage CGImage]];
```

Comment: Make sure to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883208/how-to-change-background-color-of-uialertview/1478873#1478873 for some suggestions for improvement

Comment: how can i make the image to scale until it fits the alertview??

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Is there a requirement for the image size as right now I am using a hi-resolution image.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work on iOS 4.2 anymore... i've been using this on earlier iOS... im still finding another way.

Comment: it's still showing the default alert background on top of my custom image...any idea?

Answer (score 13):

I've also find an almost identical workaround and, in my case, it works better. Using oxigen way out i've discovered a poor result on the screen and the context get blurred. Rather than subclassing UIAlertView I implement:

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView;
```

so...just copy & paste

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
{
    blah blah blah...
    [[alertView layer] setContents:(id)theImage.CGImage];  // to avoid the warning
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I recently needed this and ended up subclassing UIAlertView. Here is the code for anyone who is interested.

http://kwigbo.com/post/318396305/iphone-sdk-custom-uialertview-background-color

Comment: This solution is nice in that there in that there is no need to produce a background image, however it doesn't quite look as good as the version that Apple made.

Answer (score 7):

Well i solved the problem in a different way. I searched for the UIImageView which contains the background image and change the image.

... well show is maybe not the best solution for altering the view ...

```
@implementation CustomAlertView

- (void)show {
    [super show];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"%@ with %i children", view, [view.subviews count]);
        // change the background image
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"password entry bg - default.png"];    
            ((UIImageView *)view).image = [theImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(49, 8, 8, 8)];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: This approach still works as of iOS 5, and the replacement of the image can be done in the '- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView'  method, which doesn't require overriding the 'show' method.

Comment: Just thought I would clarify:  if you are creating a subclass of UIAlertView, override -(void)show.  OR you can include the code above inside of willPresentAlertView in the delegate.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a much more recent solution that takes advantage of blocks and is modeled after TweetBot:

https://github.com/Arrived/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Comment: So it is. Here's a fork of that branch: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Comment: Warning about that class - it does not know how to display itself properly when the device is rotated. It also is not compatible with iOS 3.1.x

Answer (score 3):

This is not something that is possible.

Either you need to create your own alert-type view (including providing the animation, etc.) or use the default UIAlertView supplied by Apple.

Apple tends to not expose things like the color of the UIAlertView so that the UI has a common feel across all applictions. Changing the color from app to app would be confusing to the user.

Comment: Not allowing to change the colour will make app developers create their own UI elements which could end up being even more confusing ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add QuartzCore framework to the application and include #import "QuartzCore/CALayer.h" in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"You are Select Row of" message:@"Human" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alert.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
```

it will changed the background color of UIAlertView.

Comment: This changes the backgroundcolor from clearColor to a solid color resulting in a very poor looking UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the most robust solution to me

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/

Answer (score 1):

I recently found the GRAlertView, which allow you to tailor UIAlertView in an easy way that at least I like. You find it here: https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code,

```
 UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
 UIView *view=[alert valueForKey:@"_backgroundImageView"];
 //Set frame according to adustable
  UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
 [image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 130)];
 [view addSubview:image];
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe that there is an exposed method or property for doing this.  Setting the backgroundColor of the UIAlertView (as a UIView) merely puts a colored rectangular backdrop behind the alert view.

I'd say that it would probably go against the common interface of the iPhone to alter this color, so I don't think it's recommended behavior (in the same way that changing the background color of an alert view in Mac OS X is not recommended).

Comment: True but I suppose if Apple imposes rules on us they should follow similar rules too, am I right? If you see GameKit's AlertViews all of them are with black background colour. Strange!