# show alert in home screen

Tags: iphone

I would like to make a alertView that can show in any where and don't care there is a View or Window.It just like the safe-model alert can show on the desktop which also can accept user input.
The UIAlertView and UIActiveSheet are build upon a UIView or Window.So I didn't need these kinds.I also know the application called backgrouder has such a alert,but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: If you're asking about customizing an instance of UIAlertView, there are several questions here already about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765599/how-to-create-custom-uialertview are near the top of the search results. Not sure about the rest of your question - can you clarify what you mean by "I didn't need these kinds" and "can show in any where and don't care there is a View or Window"? (In an iPhone app, there is always a UIWindow, and you don't have to use classes you don't need.)

Comment: I need my alertView could show on the desktop where list a lot of app ico, just like sms message alert box,it didn't need a UIWindow or UIView and can shou alone.

Comment: You'd better rename the title to "How to show alert view in home screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The only way to get your message displayed on the home screen like an SMS is to PUSH this message to the user. Pre condition is that your user has accepted push notifications from your application, and that you're using the Apple Push Notification Service to push info to your users.