# how to display the alert message with multiple custom buttons and with back ground image?

Tags: iphone, ios5

hi how to implement code for multiple custom buttons Alert message code and how to set the backgound custom image for the alert message so give guide for my request in iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for my own like this,

```
UIView *myAlertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 190.0, 110.0, 100.0)];
myAlertView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:myAlertView];

UIImageView *imgAlertBack = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myAlertView.frame];
imgAlertBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AlertBackgroundImageWithNiceCurves.png"];
[myAlertView addSubview:imgAlertBack];

[myAlertView addSubview:<add your buttons>];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to implement and customize alertview,  there is some tutorial about this follow this
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/

[Customizing UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview)

http://kwigbo.com/post/318396305/iphone-sdk-custom-uialertview-background-color

[How to create custom UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765599/how-to-create-custom-uialertview)