# iOS 5 black transparent UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5, uialertview

I'm aware that this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883208/changing-the-background-color-of-a-uialertview) for earlier versions of iOS, however, as far as I remember, people at the WWDC this year emphasised that we can finally customise everything very easily, e.g. the tint colours of switches (UISwitch onTintColor etc.).

I had a look at the AlertView but the only options are password input / text input. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here, but is it still not possible to change the background tint colour of an UIAlertView in iOS 5 easily? All the other UIAlertViews in iOS are blackish/transparent, so there should be an easy way or not?

I checked the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) but couldn't find anything specific for iOS 5.

Comment: Black alert views called HUDs, it's private API. However you can google for MBProgressHUD and SVProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if the background color can be changed that easily in iOS5 but traditionally speaking changing `UIAlertView` background is to do with setting a new image. The link you provided & [this link](http://kwigbo.com/post/318396305/iphone-sdk-custom-uialertview-background-color) provide help.