# Customise Pop Over AlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

Can we edit the `PopOverAlert`.... Is it possible to customise the `UIAlertView`. Also I want to make the `UIAlertView` transparent.

Comment: which type of Alertview you need exactly?

Comment: alertview which can show the background page. that is AlertView must be transparent

Comment: means alertview design is as it is just you need to transparent alertview. right?

Comment: Yes have you check my answer's first link of tutsplus?

Comment: Actually I have done this coding in a button action..**
        alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"qwwqreqrgvsdfhbsb" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss"otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
        
        [alert show];
        
        UILabel *theTitle = [alert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
        [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        UILabel *theBody = [ alert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
        [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];                                **now I want to know what will be the code to make the view of alert transparent?

Comment: yes but I had created AlertView as like above.And i couldn't understand where i have to start. to set the alert view as transparent

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can customize the UIAlertView ... Depends On what you actually want to do ... Use these links [Changing the background color of a UIAlertView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883208/changing-the-background-color-of-a-uialertview) and [how can I have a totally transparent UIAlertView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243489/how-can-i-have-a-totally-transparent-uialertview)

Comment: But these links cant satisfy me.I want to make my alertview transparent.Is it possible? can anyone specify me any code.

Comment: @goku Dont make a UIAlertView ... Make a UIView , and customize it in such a way using animations such that it looks like a UIAlertView...

Answer (score 0):

see the customise alertview over here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/ and here http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/09/customized-alertview.html