# Change color of UIAlertView in UILocalNotification

Tags: uialertview

I have implemented UILocalNotification in my application it is working fine  but i want to customize the alert view shown ie change the color of UIAlertview is there any way to implement it.Please help..

Thanks

Comment: Possible to Duplicate Question [Get Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883208/changing-the-background-color-of-a-uialertview

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the GRAlertView, which you find here: [GRAlertView github page](https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView)